# Crystal Reports: group by one field, sort by another

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an "Orders" table:

```
+---------+-------------+
| OrderID | InvoiceDate |
+---------+-------------+
| 1       | 15/02/2022  |
| 123     | 20/01/2022  |
+---------+-------------+
```

and a "Rows" table:

```
+---------+-------+--------+
| OrderID | RowID | Value  |
+---------+-------+--------+
| 1       |     1 | 100,00 |
| 1       |     2 | 200,00 |
| 1       |     3 |  50,00 |
| 123     |     1 |  10,00 |
| 123     |     2 |  20,00 |
+---------+-------+--------+
```

As shown in the example, it may happen that an order with a higher `OrderID` value has a lower `InvoiceDate` value.

In my report I would like to show each order, along with the sum of each row's value, ordered by date:

```
+-------------+---------+--------+
| InvoiceDate | OrderID | Value  |
+-------------+---------+--------+
| 20/01/2022  | 123     |  30,00 |
| 15/02/2022  | 1       | 350,00 |
+-------------+---------+--------+
```

My problem is that in order to create an `OrderValue` formula field with `Sum({Rows.Value}, {Orders.OrderID})`, I first need to group by `Rows.OrderID`

But this way rows are sorted by `OrderID`, and I don't know how to sort them by date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a group total of Maximum (or minimum, or Average) Order Date by Order ID.

Go to the menu option of ***Report, Group Sort Expert...***
and sort the groups by that total.